# sequelize with nested table gives only one entry but actually there are more entries present in nested table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

let assignmentData = await Assignment.findAll({
attributes: ['id', 'name', 'assignee_type', 'assignee_id','start_date','end_date','is_active'],
include: [
{
model: GameAssignment,
attributes: ['game_id'],
required: false
}
],
where: {
user_id: req.userData.Id
},
order: [['id', 'ASC']]
});

```
output came like:-
```

{
"id": 4,
"name": "child assig 1",
"assignee_type": 1,
"assignee_id": 1654002,
"start_date": "2023-04-02 05:54:19",
"end_date": "2023-05-28 05:54:19",
"is_active": 1,
"game_assignments": [
{
"game_id": 1
}
]
}

Comment: Please format both pieces of text with code and JSON

Comment: Here is relevant help page for [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)